# where to place the comma

Tags: punctuation

Where would you put the comma or comma's for a subordinating Conjunction comma?

1. When you finish vacuuming the rugs please mop the floor.
2. If you finish early we can go to the mall.

only after rugs?   and only after early?

Comment: The positioning of the text up to and including ***rugs/early*** could be seen as examples of [fronting](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/frontingterm.htm). Standard grammar dictates that when moved in this way, the "fronted" clause is separated from the main clause by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you finish vacuuming the rugs, please mop the floor.
2. If you finish early, we can go to the mall.

It helps if you say it aloud and take the pauses at the commas